# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined - old Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm updating an old project that used jquery-1.4.3.min.js. This was interfering with some new  stuff I was working on so I had to replace it with the up to date verson, and now I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined.

Been working on this one for a while and I'm stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The line it's from

```
$link = $('a[hash=#' + $inview + ']').parent().attr('id').substr(4);
```

Here's the whole bit if needed

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $inview = $('section:in-viewport header').parent().attr('id');
    if ($('a[hash=#' + $inview + ']') !== null) {
        $link = $('a[hash=#' + $inview + ']').parent().attr('id').substr(4);
    }

    if ($link != $nCurrentActive && scrolling == 1) {
        $nav.removeClass('active');
        offMenu($nCurrentActive);
        $nCurrentActive = $link;
        $('#nav-'+$nCurrentActive).addClass('active');
        onScrollMenu($nCurrentActive);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @stanced, Can you provide fiddle with some HTML ?

Comment: You might want to escape the attribute selector properly... if your ID contains `'`, `"` or `[space]` characters that are unescaped that will render the attribute selector invalid.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes in your code. It's no use to fix just one of them.

- You did not use `var` to declare your local variables. This a *big* mistake you must never make.
- You use global variables (like `$nCurrentActive`, `$nav`, `scrolling`) to stave state. Don't do that. Yes I know it's convenient. Just don't.
- You use `$` to prefix variables that do not contain a jQuery object (`$inview`, `$link`). Don't do that.
- You compare the result of a jQuery call to `null`. This is useless, since a jQuery call *never* results in `null`.
- You call `substr()` on a function result without checking that that function *actually returned something* (`$(...).attr("id").substr(...)`). **That's the source of the error you see.**

Better:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var sectionId, sectionLinkId, navId;

    sectionId = $('section:in-viewport header').parent().attr('id');
    if (!sectionId) return;

    sectionLinkId = $('a[hash=#' + sectionId + ']').parent().attr('id');
    if (!sectionLinkId) return;

    navId = sectionLinkId.substr(4);
    offMenu(navId);
    $("*[id^=nav]").removeClass("active").filter("#nav+" + navId).addClass("active");
    onScrollMenu(navId);
});
```

Other notes:

- You don't seem to use good variable names. Think harder if a variable name actually reflects what the variable contains.
- Work with CSS classes (`$(".navLink")`) is *way* better than `$("*[id^=nav]")`).
- You don't need and should not use a global variable like `$nCurrentActive`. Use `$(".navLink.active")`, that's what classes are for.
- Why all this complex fumbling with IDs and part of IDs? Wouldn't it be better if your HTML structure was such that you could simply do `$('section:in-viewport a.primarySectionLink')` to select the primary section link?
- One way to avoid multiple levels of nested `if` statements is to return early when it's clear that the function's preconditions are not met (like seen above).
- You should not have to call `offMenu()` and `onScrollMenu()`. Let the menu handle the Window scroll event on its own. Why would you want to establish a dependency between these two functions?
- You do not handle the case where more than one section is in the viewport.